# Query for all records with a status plus the last one (no matter what status) in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have something like:

`(Model.where(status: :active).to_a << Model.last).uniq`

I'm looking for a way to make it happen in one single query. Is that possible?

Comment: In SQL, you would normally use UNION

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a single query, maybe you can do a query with a nested subquery but you can't do that easy with just ActiveRecord (maybe with Arel).

Personally, I would use 2 ActiveRecord queries, one to get the las record's id and then the actual query:

```
last_id = Model.last.id
records = Model.where(status: active).or(Model.where(id: last_id))
```

You'll have 2 queries but the first one will be really depreciable and the second one is a lot faster than turning all the results into an array and doing `uniq`.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a query with plain SQL, and then use `ActiveRecord#find_by_sql` to get array of ActiveRecord objects:

```rb
query = <<-SQL
  SELECT * FROM subscriptions
  WHERE
   status = 'active' OR
   id = (SELECT max(id) FROM subscriptions)
SQL

Subscription.find_by_sql(query) #=> [ array of subscriptions]
```

If you need a ActiveRecord::Relation instance, use `ActiveRecord#from` method. It allows to pass plain SQL into FROM statement. Since `#from` returns relation you can use all Active Record methods for querying

```rb
Subscription.from(query).where('created_at > ?', Time.zone.now)
```

It builds single query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM subscriptions
  WHERE
   status = 'active' OR
   id = (SELECT max(id) FROM subscriptions)
) WHERE created_at > '2019-01-01 00:00'
```